# how to send AMFObject to server with libRTMP.a

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to develop a chat function using RTMP, so I got and compiled libRTMP.

How can I send an `NSDictionary` to the sever?

I used `AMFObject`, but there is an error when Xcode compiles.

```
    RTMPPacket packet;
    char pbuf[1024];
    char *pend = pbuf + sizeof(pbuf);
    char *enc;
    //块流ID为4
    packet.m_nChannel = 0x04;   /* source channel (invoke) */
    packet.m_headerType = RTMP_PACKET_SIZE_LARGE;
    packet.m_packetType = RTMP_PACKET_TYPE_INVOKE;  /* INVOKE */
    packet.m_nTimeStamp = (uint32_t)[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    //流ID
    packet.m_nInfoField2 = sendRtmp->m_stream_id;
    packet.m_hasAbsTimestamp = 0;
    packet.m_body = pbuf + RTMP_MAX_HEADER_SIZE;
    //指向Chunk的负载
    enc = packet.m_body;

    /*组装方法*/
    AVal methodName;
    NSString *methodNameString = @"login1";
    methodName.av_val = (char*)[methodNameString UTF8String];
    methodName.av_len = (int)[[methodNameString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] length];
    //对“publish”字符串进行AMF编码
    enc = AMF_EncodeString(enc, pend, &methodName);
    enc = AMF_EncodeNumber(enc, pend, ++sendRtmp->m_numInvokes);
    *enc++ = AMF_NULL;

    struct AMFObject *object = (struct AMFObject *)malloc(sizeof(struct AMFObject));
    struct AMFObjectProperty *property = (struct AMFObjectProperty *)malloc(sizeof(struct AMFObjectProperty));
    /*key*/
    AVal key;
    NSString *keyString = @"name";
    key.av_val = (char*)[keyString UTF8String];
    key.av_len = (int)[[keyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] length];

    /*value*/
    AVal value;
    NSString *valueString = @"liubo";
    value.av_val = (char*)[valueString UTF8String];
    value.av_len = (int)[[valueString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] length];
    AMFProp_SetName(property, &key);
    AMFProp_SetString(property, &value);
    AMF_AddProp(object, property);
    AMF_Encode(object, enc, pend);
    enc = AMF_EncodeNumber(enc, pend, ++sendRtmp->m_numInvokes);
    *enc++ = AMF_NULL;

    free(object);
    free(property);

    if (!enc)
        return;

    packet.m_nBodySize = enc - packet.m_body;

    int code = RTMP_SendPacket(sendRtmp, &packet, TRUE);
    NSLog(@"发送消息完毕：%@  返回值：%d",message,code);
```

And there is the error when Xcode compile:

[image]

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_AMFProp_SetString", referenced from:
      -[KKRTMPClient startSendMessage] in KKRTMPClient.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 1):

I found the same error with AMFProp_SetString on iOS. I add properties this way :

```
AMFObject object;
object.o_props = malloc(sizeof(AMFObjectProperty *)); // Needs a malloc for AMF_AddProp

AMFObjectProperty prop;

AVal name = AVC("test");
AVal nothing = AVC("");

prop.p_type = AMF_STRING;
prop.p_vu.p_aval = name;
prop.p_name = nothing;

object.o_num = 0;

AMF_AddProp(&object, &prop);
```

Hope it helps.